# Setting spinner on tab Layout in android

Tags: android

I have three tabs in my activity and i want to implement spinner on third tab only.Third activity will fetch certain values from API and list.The spinner will sort the list view.My doubt is where should i declare spinner. I am new to android.Can anyone me guidance?

[image]

Comment: I have this spinner just under a datepicker

Comment: LinearLayout...Bro my problem is i have added this spinner on xml file. Normally spinner details will be added under oncreate .But in my case i dont know where to put due to spinner is only on third tab header.